# best practice way, to create an array of pointers to a typdef, in a library, and pass its pointer to other source modules

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, static, parameter-passing

I am creating a library.
A top level critical array of pointers to a typdef needs to be returned from the init function.
What is the best way to do this?

do I create the array outside of the Init function,
... and declare it extern in other source modules?

```
myType *myArray[256];

void Init()
{
  // seed the 1st element.
  myArray[0] = malloc(sizeof(myType));

  // initialize some variables in the 1st myType.
}
```

... or do I do it all in Init:

```
// library.c
void *Init()
{
  static myType *myArray[256];

  // seed the 1st element.
  myArray[0] = malloc(sizeof(myType));

  // initialize some variables in the 1st myType.

  return myArray;
}

// main.c
extern myType *myArray[256];

int main ()
{
   myArray = Init();
}
```

... or something else entirely?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't use `extern` to make `static myType *myArray[256];` available outside of the function it was defined in. You can only make variables available in another file if they are defined at file scope.

Comment: Thanks Weather Vane ... i'll stick with the global method.